# C++ : Covariant return type without pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, covariant-return-types

I create two simple classes by inheritance, and I add a virtual function and the override in the child class.

```cpp
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual Parent foo();
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child foo() override;
};
```

In this case, my overridden function get an error : `error C2555: 'Child::foo': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'Parent::foo'`

If I change return types with pointer :

```cpp
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual Parent* foo();
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child* foo() override;
};
```

the error gone !
I don't understand why the covariance of return types must be done with pointer and I can't use value type or a reference.
Some website or forums explain that because the returned value is a copy of the value used in the function, the compiler know the constant size of a pointer, but must indicate different size for the overridden function and the parent function, which is apparently impossible.

So, why can't I use anything else than pointer in this case ?
If I want the child type in the overridden function without using pointers, must I return the base class for each functions and cast the returned type into the child type ?

Comment: Minor aside: it doesn't have to involve pointers--you can use references as well.

Comment: "function without using pointers, must I return the base class for each functions and cast the returned type into the child type" no you cannot cast a Parent object to Child. The returned object is a full object There's no Child. If you say `return child;` the `Child` object you want to return gets *sliced* and a copy of only the `Parent` part is returned.

Comment: Consider the case where the base class is abstract (as it often should be for an interface class): you wouldn't even be able to return it an object of that class, ever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of a covariant return type is a polymorpihc return type. And in C++, you can't have run time polymorphism without pointers or references. Let's ignore for a second most of the hardships, and pretend it's possible. Here is my code that handles things by your `Parent` interface:

```
void bar(Parent * p) {
  auto o = p->foo();
}
```

What is `o`? Well, it's `Parent` of course. Says so in `Parent::foo`'s return type. But what if that `p` is pointing at a `Child`? The deduced type of `o` is still `Parent`, so at best I get a sliced object. No polymorphic behavior, so the whole exercise is pointless.

At worst, and quite likely, I get undefined behavior.

That's why co-variant return types have to be pointers or references.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the derived type would return a derived instance but the caller would be expecting a parent, this is different from when using pointers, in the pointer case the derived pointer can just slide into the space reserved for the parent pointer but the same is not true when talking about actual instances. You also have the problem that the derived method would return a derived instance but a caller using a parent pointer would have no idea about that and thus probably only destroy the parent parts.

you can find [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/240862/fix-c2555-on-virtual-functions-with-covariant-return-types) helpful

Comment: You mean that [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/nonstandard-behavior?view=vs-2017)?